# McAfee Web Gateway blocking HTTP file download

Tags: activex, jscript, mcafee

I have a script that was working for quite some time:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("microsoft.xmlhttp");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://myurl.csv", false);
xmlhttp.send();
var data=xmlhttp.responsetext;

dt = new Date();
month = dt.getMonth() +1
date = dt.getDate()
year = dt.getFullYear()

var fileloc = "\\\\fs1\\myshare$\\myfolder\\" + "my_query_export" + "-" + month + "-" + date + "-" + year + ".csv"
var file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileloc,true);
file.writeLine(data);
file.close();
```

Recently, however, after executing this script the downloaded file contains this:

*If you opened this file and can see this text, then you've probably tried to download a file using
the 'save target as' option in the context menu when right clicking the object. Since McAfee Web Gateway is used for virus scanning your browser is redirected to a page that will show the download
progress, and by choosing the 'save target as' option you were saving this progress page. To avoid
this situation please use a simple click with the left mouse button to download the object. This
will correctly redirect your browser to display the download progress and allow you to save the
desired object.*

How can I revise this code to download and save the CSV instead of this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this!

The key was to switch from HTTP to HTTPS and install the website certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.